# Program does not create output file

Tags: c, file, encryption

I have to write a program that receives the arguments (**ex: `-in cypher/in/in2.txt -out cypher/out/out2.txt -key 0 -mode enc -alg  caesar`**) and it has to do the encrypt/decrypt operation on the text from "in" file and print the output in the "out" file.

Because we are many students, to check our programs, the teacher has made/downloaded a program "checker" that gives 7 tests like the one from the example and compares the output file with one called ref file. 
I've done the encrypt algorithms but I've met a problem: when I run the tests "manually" (from cmd -introducing parameters, or just inserting them in vs-proprieties-debugging) the program works well. It creates the output files, exactly as the one from ref. But when I run the checker, the program doesn't create the output files.

I've noticed something interesting,in the folder where I have the source, after I run the checker it appears some files, with the name of some arguments (**ex: `-hint`, `-alg`, with no extension**) that contain what should be in the output file. I've used debugging in VS and checked the name of the output file and it is correct. But still when I run it "manually" the files are build correctly and when using the checker it doesn't even create them.(the program was verified by some friend and it seems no to have any writing issues).

[here is a pic with the folder created after running the checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHTSy.png)

Here I've rebuild the first part of the program just to solve the output problem; it's not the full program, but at the first test, in the checker it should return :Missing input file!

```
void ordonare_argumente(int n, char *p[]) {
    int v[20];
    int g[20], k = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        char *j;
        j = p[i];
        if (j[0] == '-') {
            for (size_t u = 1; u < strlen(j); u++)
                sum = sum + j[u];
            k++;
            v[k] = sum;
            g[k] = i;

        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= k - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= k; j++)
            if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                char **pahar = (char**)malloc(1000);
                int aux = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = aux;

                pahar[g[i]] = p[g[j]];
                p[g[j]] = p[g[i]];
                p[g[i]] = pahar[g[i]];

                pahar[g[i] + 1] = p[g[j] + 1];
                p[g[j] + 1] = p[g[i] + 1];
                p[g[i] + 1] = pahar[g[i] + 1];
                free(pahar);

            }
}
```

The function from above sorts the arguments by the ASCII sum and what's immediate after so that I know the exact meaning of each argument

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char f_out[30];
    FILE *intrare;

    ordonare_argumente(argc, argv);

    if (argc != 11)  strcpy(f_out, argv[4]);
    else strcpy(f_out, argv[8]);
    if ((intrare = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL) {
        FILE *iesire = fopen(f_out, "w");
        fprintf(iesire, "Missing the input file");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argumentul nr %d este:%s\n ", i, argv[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `fopen` and other functions like that will return errors. Check for those.

Comment: If your program works when run from the debugger or when you run it yourself I suspect (though do not know for sure) that it is a matter of where files are being placed, that when the checker runs the files are in fact created, just not where you expect them to be.

Comment: Thanks both @SoronelHaetir and @-tadman . The function fopen does not return any error. I think he is making the files in other directories but still cannot find out why. Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Looks like checker passes arguments in the different order. You should not treat them as positional, but parse the command line properly and rely on the options (`-in`, `-out`, `-key`, etc).